# Can you use the -ly suffix with any noun? e.g "Hotelly"

Tags: word-usage, suffixes

A friend and I were having a discussion when I used the word "hotelly" to describe something that has the characteristics of a hotel. Afterward, we started doubting the legitimacy of the word "hotelly" as it doesn't appear in any dictionary or anything of the likes. So we have a question, can you append -ly to ANY noun to form a new adjective? Is "hotelly" a legitimate word in the English language? Or is there some rule on when you can and can't use -ly as a suffix?

Comment: A suffix that would work better is “ish”—hotellish, like a hotel.

Comment: @hotlicks Yes, got it.

Comment: A cover rule is that productivity is very often gradeable in English. That is, rules are rarely universal (this one perhaps being _the_ exception). // Do 'boxly', 'cardly', 'aardvarkly', 'inkwellly' sound/look right to you? You could have checked for a few more non-words like these. //  But 'boxy', 'bloody', 'worthy', 'mighty', 'healthy',  'rocky', 'risky' ... are some examples of the form [noun+'y'}. 'Shiny', 'tinny', 'easy', 'muddy'... show the -y ending after a slight adjustment.// 'Aardvarky', 'Bread-y' etc (Genius Holly & Talkie Toaster) are  'childspeak' nonce usages, not in the lexicon.

Comment: Also ***hotel-like-***.  (Which, in my lexicon at least, purports to be more like a hotel than *hotelish*;  -*ish* has a “sorta/kinda flavor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible that you've confused the suffixes *-ly* and *-y* in this case.

As Hot Licks mentioned, *-ly* is mainly used in English to turn an adjective into an adverb: for example, the adjective *cold* + *-ly* = the adverb *coldly.* The adverb-forming suffix *-ly* is not attached to nouns.

There are some adjectives that are formed from nouns + *-ly,* such as *friendly, daily, manly, kingly, godly, homely, sisterly,* but this is not a common structure for newly formed adjectives.

Newly formed adjectives that are derived from nouns are more likely to use *-ish* (as Francis and Xanne mentioned) or *-y.* I would interpret "hotelly" as *hotel* + *-y,* with the double ll being the result of the spelling rule about doubling consonant letters in certain contexts before vowel-initial suffixes (compare *sun* and *sunny*). This use of *-y* doesn't have any strong restrictions that I know of, but it is informal and not a very frequent device. Examples of *hotelly* being used:

- "not annoyed by very **hotelly** hotel prices" -- *[The Spectator,](https://books.google.com/books?id=vSNDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=%22very+hotelly%22)* August 13, 1892
- "Did I miss some shortcut here, do you think this is an element of creating a very **hotelly** feeling or something like that or is this waste of my time just bad game design?" -- "[the lift in the hotel](https://steamcommunity.com/app/569860/discussions/0/1290690926868587324/?l=romanian)", Thimbleweed Park discussion on Steam, May 21 2017

For comparison: I think the analogous adjective for "apartment" would be *apartmenty,* not *apartmently.* See these examples:

- "I would read the reviews of the entire complex to decide. They are very **apartmenty**, close together, no views, many people live there full time." https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60626-i828-k8026548-Princeville_Condo_Rental_anyone_stayed_here-Princeville_Kauai_Hawaii.html
- "We recently moved from the area where we had been for 20 years ... always loved it although it has become very "apartmenty" and the population has expanded" https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g255068-i461-k12757150-Moving_to_Brissi_where_to_live-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html

New or "nonce" formations with "y" are sometimes enclosed in quotation marks, as in that last example, or are written with a hyphen between the base and suffix (like "hotel-y" or "apartment-y").

Answer (score 1):

"-ly" is a suffix that is commonly used to turn an adjective (eg, "quick") into an adverb ("quickly"), as in "He quickly decided to quit while he was ahead".

It is sometimes used informally to turn a noun into an adjective (as in your example of "hotel" -> "hotelly"), but that is not a standard technique in English.  As Xanne suggests, "-ish" is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

From dictionary.com, definition of *-ish*

a suffix used to form adjectives from nouns, with the sense of “belonging to” (British; Danish; English; Spanish); “after the manner of,” “having the characteristics of,” “like” (babyish; girlish; mulish); “addicted to,” “inclined or tending to” (bookish; freakish); “near or about” (fiftyish; sevenish).

a suffix used to form adjectives from other adjectives, with the sense of “somewhat,” “rather” (oldish; reddish; sweetish).

Answer (score 0):

"Hotelly" is not a word, and the suffix *-ly* is more commonly used for adverbs. *-ish* is more commonly used for adjectives. However, neither of these techniques can guarantee an entry in the dictionary. Just because a noun exists doesn't mean one can arbitrarily tack on an *-ish* and it's magically an official adjective. It's definitely okay to use this in informal contexts, e.g. when talking with a friend as you stated. If the word makes sense and becomes common and widespread in usage, then it is likely that it will enter the dictionary. If you are the first to use an adjective like this and it catches on, then congratulations, you just coined a new word! However, it is very impractical for every noun to automatically have an *-ish* variant: for example, the word "bicyclish" does not exist in any dictionary. A better alternative to "a bicyclish object" would be "an object like/resembling/(plug in whatever synonym you like) a bicycle." So the final verdict is that don't use it in formal contexts unless you know for sure it is a word or you think it makes sense as a word, use it in informal contexts as much as you want, and you can add in a few words to the description if you just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this question is, thinking of words which actually take -ly as suffix such as manly, womanly, cowardly, miserly and so on. These words are legitimate parts of the English speaking communities.

But then again, there are words that you can make for yourself so that it gives an idea of a quality, not easily put in words.

You go to a prom and expect to be carefree and not tied up to a chair, but just the opposite happens. You cant find the word for the feeling, so you can say 
the schoolly or school-ly  atmosphere. You know that it doesn't have any formal meaning, but, it works.

The same ideology can be used with -y and -ish as well.

Comment: '[T]here are words that you can make for yourself' doesn't concur with the accepted definition of 'word', which requires that a reasonable number of people understand what it means and use it and/or that it appears in a respectable dictionary (OED contains archaisms, for example).